# The sum of a double series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

- Let $j,n \geq 0$ be integers.
- I am interested in the double series defined as
  $$
  \sum_{m\ \geq\ 0}\ \sum_{k\ \geq\ 0}
  \frac{2^{m}\,\left(-1\right)^{m + k}}{m!\,k!} \binom{m}{j}\binom{k + 1}{n}.
  $$
- I checked with software that for small values of $j$ and $n$, the double series has a closed form
  $$
  \frac{2^{j}\left(-1\right)^{\,j + n}\
  \left(1 - n\right)}{j!\,n!}\,\mathrm{e}^{-3},
  $$
  but I could not prove this. Of course the above closed form may not work for larger values of $j$ and $n$.

Could you please help $?$. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your summation seems to just be a product of two sums. I believe the sums should start at $k = n-1$ and $m = j$ respectively because that's presumably the first place we define the binomial coefficients to be non-zero. Then we have:

$$\left(\sum_{m=j}^\infty \frac{(-2)^mm!}{m!(m-j)!j!}\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{k =n-1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(k+1)!}{k!n!(k-(n-1)!)}\right) = A\cdot B$$
To find $B$, after reindexing we have:
$$B = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(k+n)}{k!} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\right) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\left(-e^{-1}+ne^{-1}\right)}{n!}\implies B =  (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)e^{-1}}{n!}$$
We also have $$A = \frac{(-2)^j}{j!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^m}{m!} =\frac{(-2)^je^{-2}}{j!}$$
So all together we have:$$A\cdot B = \frac{(n-1)(-1)^{j+n-1}2^je^{-3}}{n!j!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Separating the $m$ terms and the $k$ terms using Fubini we get a product of two sums, using the definition of the binomial coefficient the first sum is :
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} {{k+1} \choose n} =  \sum_{k=n-1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{n!} \frac{k+1}{(k+1-n)!}. $$
Using the change of index $k+1-n \to k$ we get
$$ \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(k+n)(-1)^{k+n-1}}{k!} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{1-n}{e}.$$
By the same method the second sum gives :
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-2)^m}{m!} {m \choose j} =\frac{1}{j!} \sum_{m=j}^{+\infty} \frac{(-2)^m}{(m-j)!} = \frac{2^j (-1)^j}{j!} \frac{1}{e^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \sum_{m \geq 0} \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{2^{m}(-1)^{m+k}}{m!k!} \binom{m}{j} \binom{k+1}{n} \\
&=& \frac{2^j (-1)^{j+n}}{j!n!}  \sum_{m \geq 0}  \frac{(-2)^{m-j}}{(m-j)!}  \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(n-(n-k-1))(-1)^{k-n}}{(n-k-1)!} \\
&=& \frac{2^j (-1)^{j+n}}{j!n!}  \sum_{m \geq 0}  \frac{(-2)^{m-j}}{(m-j)!} \left(-n \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{k+1-n}}{(n-k-1)!} \color{red}{-}\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n-k-2}}{(n-k-2)!} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}